# GCP transcoder API is very slow with HEVC (h.265) videos

Tags: google-cloud-platform, transcoding, google-cloud-transcoder

Processing videos from iphone (15 pro) encoded with h.265:

```
Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/arib-std-b67), 1920x1080, 15043 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn (default)
```

Transcoding takes around 10x playing time, e.g. for 3 minute video total processing time is close to 30 minutes.
Is it possible to speed it up?

Transcoding from h.265 to h.264, very fast profile. Size of the video file 390MB.

Comment: Hi @user2524940, What is the size of the video file that you are transcoding ?

Comment: @DhirajSingh the one that took 30 minutes was 390MB.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this google **[documentation](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/concepts/overview#limits)**, where we can find some limitations of the GCP Transcoder API. Also in the key point it states that, Transcoder API does not provide strong guarantees around the timing of job processing and hence it is unsuitable for interactive applications where a user waits for the result. The Transcoder API service is designed for asynchronous work.

You can also open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue to get more details and clarification.